# How to make a Ajax search with Symfony and Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

hi guys i'm working in symfony project and i would like to do a realtime search using ajax.
I tried but its not working, for some reason, returns all datas from the database and not the data that i'm searching using keyup.
Can anyone help me please.
here is my code

```
<div id="div">
    </div>

    <table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>Id</td><td>Libelle</td><td>pays</td>
    </tr>
    {% for i in voitures %} 
            <tr>
            <td>{{ i.id}}</td>
            <td>{{ i.libelle}}</td>
            <td>{{ i.pays}}</td>

           </tr>
     {% endfor %}
    </table>
    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
    {{ form_end(form) }}

     <script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
     <script>
     $("#myapp_parcbundle_marque_libelle").keyup(
            function(){
                 var serie=$('#myapp_parcbundle_marque_libelle').val();
                var DATA = 'serie=' + serie;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{ path('demo_create')}}",
                    data:DATA,
                    success: function (msg) {
                        $( "#div" ).html( msg );
                    }
                });
            });

</script>
```

Controller

```
function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $voiture = new Marque();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $voitures=$em->getRepository('MyAppParcBundle:Marque')->findAll();
    $Form = $this->createForm(RechercheForm::class, $voiture);
    $Form->handleRequest($request);

    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()&&($Form->isValid())){

        $voitures = $em->getRepository("MyAppParcBundle:Marque")
            ->findBy(array('serie'=>$voiture->getSerie()));
        return new JsonResponse($voitures);

    }
    return $this->render(
        'MyAppParcBundle:Marque:Recherche2.html.twig',
        array("voitures" => $voitures,
            "form" => $Form->createView()));

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [live search using Symfony and Ajax jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265767/live-search-using-symfony-and-ajax-jquery)

Comment: Have you tried adding a console log on your `var DATA = 'serie=' + serie;` to make sure you are getting the expected value your input `#myapp_parcbundle_marque_libelle` should hold ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so i fixed the probleme my controller whould be :

```
function testAction(Request $request)
{
    $voiture = new Marque();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $voitures=$em->getRepository('MyAppParcBundle:Marque')->findAll();
    $Form = $this->createForm(RechercheForm::class, $voiture);
    $Form->handleRequest($request);
    if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
        $serializer = new Serializer(array(new ObjectNormalizer()));
        $voitures=$em->getRepository('MyAppParcBundle:Marque')
            ->findBy(array('libelle'=>$request->get('libelle')));
        $data = $serializer->normalize($voitures);
        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
    return $this->render(
        'MyAppParcBundle:Marque:Recherche2.html.twig',
        array("voitures" => $voitures,
            "form" => $Form->createView()));

}
```

and i changed the view :

```
<div id="div">
</div>

<div id="affichage">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Id</td><td>Libelle</td><td>pays</td>
        </tr>
        {% for i in voitures %}

            <tr>
                <td>{{ i.id}}</td>
                <td>{{ i.libelle}}</td>
                <td>{{ i.pays}}</td>

            </tr>

        {% endfor %}
    </table>

</div>
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
<script>

    $("#myapp_parcbundle_marque_libelle").keyup(
            function(){
                var serie=$('#myapp_parcbundle_marque_libelle').val();
                var DATA =  {'libelle' : serie};
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "{{ path('demo_create')}}",
                    data:DATA,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data,function(k,el) {
                            $("#affichage").hide();
                            $( "#div" ).html("<ul></ul>");
                            $('ul').append(
                                    "<li>"+el.libelle+"</li>"+
                                    "<li>"+el.pays+"</li>"
                            );
                        });
                    },
                    error:function ()
                    {
                        console.log("error "+DATA);
                    }
                });
            });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you `POST` a form, Symfony fills in the data for you. In AJAX, you have to handle the `POST` yourself.

## The problem:

You're using `$voiture = new Marque();` instead of `serie; // sent by your $.ajax()`.

You've `POST`'d only one piece of data to Symfony, not the whole form, so `$form->handleRequest();` (which fills in `$voiture` with the `POST` data) **won't work**.

```
// function testAction()
// ...
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest() && $Form->isValid()) {
    $voitures = $em->getRepository("MyAppParcBundle:Marque")
        ->findBy(array(
            'serie' => $voiture->getSerie() // Not connected to the POST data.
        ));

    return new JsonResponse($voitures);
}
```

## The solution (you're very close):

Get the data from the `$request` ([more info](https://symfony.com/doc/current/introduction/http_fundamentals.html#symfony-request-object)):

```
if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    $voitures = $em->getRepository("MyAppParcBundle:Marque")
        ->findBySerie( // shorthand findBy(), it's optional.
            $request->get('serie')
        );

    return new JsonResponse($voitures);
}
```